# JS scope access

Tags: javascript, closures

**[UPDATE] I get confirmation that I can not do that.**

---

All:

I am pretty new to JS scope, say I have a function defined as :

```
var scope = "scope inside global";
function out(){

    var scope = "scope inside out";

    function scopeaccess(){
        console.log(scope);
    }

    scopeaccess();
    return scopeaccess;
}
var sa = out();
sa();
```

The outputs are both "scope inside out", I wonder how can I access "scope inside global" in scopeacess? Or I just want to confirm that there is no way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: […] Wait. This comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, just want to confirm this.

Comment: While the answer given is correct in the general case, in some cases the scope containing the outer variable may be captured some other way. For example, if this is run directly as a script in a browser, the outer `scope` would be accessible as `window.scope` because the top-level scope is actually the `window` object. It is not good practice to rely on this IMO.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks, so you mean I can use window.scope to refer to that global one? So how do I put that name in scopeaccess ?

Comment: `Function("return scope")()` can reach globals, but don't do it. an indirect eval should work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder how can I access "scope inside global" in scopeacess?

You cannot at all. You would need to use a different variable name for the local `var scope` so that you can access the global `scope` variable. Of course, you can also work around this by aliasing the global variable, or by passing its value around explicitly, so that it can be accessed through other means than the `scope` variable.

In your example, the names were probably only chosen to demonstrate what is going on (that closures are lexically not dynamically scoped), in actual scripts you wouldn't [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variables you need (or only by mistake).

Comment: Thanks, it seems I have to explicitly pass the variable as parameter rather than reference it externally.

Comment: @Kuan - Or just give them different variable names.  It is the name conflict that hides the higher scoped variable.

Comment: You might mention that global variables are available as named properties of the global object. In a browser that would be *window.scope* (in this case), in non–browser hosts (or those without *window*) access to the global object takes a bit more work, but `var global = (function(){return this}())` works in non–strict mode.

Comment: @RobG: I would consider that as an "alias" solution :-) I didn't want to mention it because a) we don't know whether it's really the global scope b) it complicates things and is generally a bad practise c) DarkFalcon already mentioned it